# What is the meaning of <%%= in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot find it anywhere but in the project I am working with. 
It doesn't work in the same way as `<%=` (I tried to change), but I can't understand the difference.

```
<span class="option-content" placeholder="<%=t('pages.edit.option')%>">
  <%%= content %>
</span>
```

Comment: can you provide complete expression?

Comment: Is this enough?

Comment: are you sure it's not a typo - what output does it give if it's just one %

Comment: It is used in other places as well, so I am pretty sure it is not a typo. If I remove one %, I get an exception `undefined local variable or method content `

Comment: Its explained here in he doc http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using?

Comment: I have Rails 4.2.3

Comment: It will parse your content and create <%= content %> into your view file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **ERb processes double-percent marks into single-percent marks.**

---

It looks like you're using one layer of ERb templates to generate another layer of ERb templates.

The first layer of ERb doesn't need a variable called `content`, just the `t` method:

```
<span class="option-content" placeholder="<%=t('pages.edit.option')%>">
  <%%= content %>
</span>
```

That first layer is rendered to produce the second layer:

```
<span class="option-content" placeholder="Edit">
  <%= content %>
</span>
```

As you can see, that is also an ERb template. I expect that something else, later on, takes that second ERb and uses it to render something like:

```
<span class="option-content" placeholder="Edit">
  Hello, world.
</span>
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer instead, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The ERB dock [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB) says

```
<% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
<%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
% a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
%% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
<%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
```

this means the

```
<%%= content %>
```

will will be replaced with

```
<%= value of content %>
```

Comment: so instead of `<%%=` it really should be `<%%` to generate `<%=`?

Comment: No `<%% content %%>` will be replaced with `<% value of content %>`  and `<%%= content %%>` will be replaced with `<%= value of content %>`

Comment: Thanks, it clarified things a bit! (I still have to understand why it is like this in the project, but it is a different question)